# Why does $() works in Google?

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I have not included jQuery file on my HTML page, but still `$()` works in google chrome console and it is acting as a selector, why? However, functions of jQuery are not working, but I want to know that why `$()` is working on google chrome console?

Answer (score 6):

Chrome devtools define set of useful shortcuts to query DOM. Those include `$` and `$$`. From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference?#queryselector):

> *$(selector)* returns the reference to the first DOM element with the specified CSS selector. This function is an alias for the document.querySelector() function.

Similarly, `$$(selector)` is the alias to `document.querySelectorAll(selector)` method.

So it has nothing to do with jQuery and they will only work in developer console.